# How to make a @mixin using variables, so I can call breakpoints with aliases names?

Tags: css, sass

I'm building a website with some SASS coding and I've done these @mixins for Media Queries that will later be used with @include directive.

The mixins look like this:

```
_standards.sass
// Media queries
@mixin for-phone-only 
  @media (max-width: 37.4375rem) 
    @content 

@mixin for-tablet-portrait-up 
  @media screen and (min-width: 37.5rem) 
    @content 

@mixin for-tablet-landscape-up 
  @media screen and (min-width: 56.25rem) 
    @content 

@mixin for-desktop-up 
  @media screen and (min-width: 75rem) 
    @content

@mixin for-big-desktop-up 
  @media screen and (min-width: 112.5rem) 
    @content
```

They work fine but I'd like to make it a little "smarter" than that. I was wondering if I could set up variables to be mapped with the breakpoints aliases and settings, so I could map them into mixins that would result in the same as above. Something like:

```
// sassmeister.com
// To get the Alias
@function getAlias($alias)
  $breakpointsAliases: ("xs": for-phone-only, "sm": for-tablet-portrait-up, "md": for-tablet-landascape-up, "lg": for-desktop-up, "xl": for-big-desktop-up)
  @return map-get($breakpointsAliases, $alias)
// To get the breakpoint value (e.g.:(min-width: x))
@function getBreakpoint($breakpoint)
  $breakpoints: ("xs": (max-width: 37.4375rem), "sm": (min-width: 37.5rem), "md": (min-width: 56.25rem), "lg": (min-width: 75rem), "xl": (min-width: 112.5rem))
  @return map-get($breakpoints, $breakpoint)

// Mixin 
@mixin getAlias($breakpointAlias)
  @media screen and (getBreakpoint($breakpoints))
    @content

// Calling for the query (test)
*
  @include for-phone-only
    margin: 0
```

But sassmeister tells me this is an undefined mixin, so it's not working.

```
Undefined mixin.
   ╷
15 │ ┌   @include for-phone-only
16 │ └     margin: 0
   ╵
  stdin 15:3  root stylesheet on line 15 at column 3
```

Is there an way to do this? A proper way? Or am I loosing my time here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mixin for breakpoints you may find useful:

```css
@mixin breakpoint($map) {
    $query: '';
    @if map-has-key($map, media) {$query: append($query, '#{map-get($map, media)} and');}
    @if map-has-key($map, min-width) {$query: append($query, '(min-width: #{map-get($map, min-width)})');}
    @if map-has-key($map, min-width) and map-has-key($map, max-width) {$query: append($query, "and");}
    @if map-has-key($map, max-width) {$query: append($query, '(max-width: #{map-get($map, max-width)})');}
    @media #{$query} {@content;}
}
```

Use it like this:

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
    @include breakpoint((min-width: 860px)) {
        some-property: someValue;
    }
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    @include breakpoint((min-width: 860px, max-width: 1000px)) {
        some-property: someValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but sadly this won't help my problem, which is I would like to be able to call that query for a name, like I'd do with my previous one. I guess I'll simply add variables to it.